# How can I use LINQ to get a property matching a conditional sum?

Tags: c#, linq

Ok, I get the title sounds weird, but here's my scenario. I think ts a simple query, but its hard to explain on paper. And I'm having trouble with the LINQ myself. Best to explain by example:

I have a list of objects (in psuedocode) that looks like:

```
var data = [
  {
    quantity: 123,
    rate: 0.12
  },
  {
    quantity: 456,
    rate: 0.13
  },
  {
    quantity: 3,
    rate: 0.14
  },
  {
    quantity: 92,
    rate: 0.15
  }
]
```

I am trying to generate a **LINQ** query that returns `rate` equaling the total sum of an input quantity.

**Explaination by example:**

Using the example data above, I want to find the `rate` that matches a total quantity of `581` (a variable input from elsewhere). The first three objects in my list have quantities that total 582, so I want my LINQ query to return `0.14` (the `rate` matching the condition that the total `quantity` fields is greater than my input quantity).

I should be able to use LINQ to do this, right? Its sort of a `.Sum` and a `.Where`, and that's where I'm getting confused.

Are there any references out that to address this type of scenario? **Does anyone have any experience writing a "conditional sum"?**

Comment: Do you want to write it just by on Linq query? Or is it ok for you to have multiple queries?

Comment: multiple queries is fine. I can do this in a loop so problem, but was just hoping to do it a little more cleanly in a linq statement.

Comment: Use a WHERE to filter results before using SUM.

Comment: Personally I think the Linq to do that would be harder to read than a simple loop.

Comment: alternatively if you did `foreach(var item in data)` you could add up item.quantity and return item.rate when quantity reachs/passes the threshold

Comment: @hellyale Thats my current approach. I was thinking LINQ could make this a one liner. Maybe not though.

Comment: One long one-liner normally makes life hard ;(

Comment: @Brett Linq is useful when you want the total of all items with rate of .12 
(Where there are multiple occurrences of the same rates) 
`data.Where(x => x.Rate == .12).Sum(item => item.quantity)` for example. Not to say thats the only time LINQ is useful

Comment: Your question is inconsistent; you say both that you want the total to *equal* a target value and to *exceed* a target value. Which is it?

Comment: Can any of the quantities be negative?

Comment: Are you looking for the *first time that a running total exceeds a value*, or are you looking for *the smallest subsequence of a sequence of items that total to a given value*?  For example, if you are looking for "10", and the items are "11, 1, 2, 3, 4", then in the first case "11" is the answer, and in the second, "1, 2, 3, 4" is the answer.  Those are **very different problems**. The first problem can be solved efficiently; the second problem is known to be one of the hardest problems in computer science.

Comment: Can you say why you want a query specifically? Is it because you are planning on remoting this query to a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functional programming, this would be a variation of a `reduce`.  In LINQ, the `Aggregate` method can be used for this purpose.  Psuedo-LINQ:

```
var limit = 581;
var rate = data.Aggregate((acc, cur) =>
{
    if (acc.quantity < limit)
    {
        return new
        {
            quantity = acc.quantity + cur.quantity,
            rate = cur.rate
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return acc;
    }
}).rate;
```

EDIT:  A more compact, one-line version:

```
var rate = data.Aggregate((acc,cur) => acc.quantity < limit ? new { quantity = acc.quantity + cur.quantity, rate = cur.rate } : acc).rate;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Hadn't used `Aggregate` before, and it looks to answer my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Was going for `Aggregate` but failed to get in one line :(

For the desired of *one-liner*, this is a funny usage of `LINQ` :)

```
var target = 581;
var sum = 0;
var rate = data.First(i =>(sum += i.Quantity) > target).Rate; // 0.14
```

Comment: This is a little scary to me, since the sum is mutated by the closure in the LINQ expression.  If, for example, the data was a ParallelEnumerable, this might cause a problem.  I added a one-line version using Aggregate to my answer.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach technically correct. No one on earth would like that line ... I was thinking hard for using `Aggregate` without doing `new` while you posted your answer ;P

Comment: Never do this.  A query must not cause a side effect.  Simple queries with side effects might work, but the moment you make them even slightly complicated then they start breaking in bizarre ways.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach BTW, `data.AsParallel().Aggregate` may also not work :)

Comment: @zcui93 Good point! Also `Aggregate` creates GC garbage with all those `new { ... }` inside and is inefficient because cannot exit the loop earlier. Shortly, standard LINQ is not good for such tasks.